# django - Can't install the add-on django-bootstrap-form

Tags: python, django, add-on, failed-installation, bootstrap-forms

I'm using the django-bootstrap-form addon in my few projects. I've never had a problem with the installation. I just tried and successfully installed it in a new project in Windows.

However, I'm having trouble installing this on Linux.
Below error:

```
root@debian:/var/www/redprogram# python3 -m pip install django-bootstrap-form
Collecting django-bootstrap-form
  Using cached django-bootstrap-form-3.4.tar.gz (4.4 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/var/www/redprogram/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution
        File "/var/www/redprogram/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 42, in <module>
          from . import _entry_points
        File "/var/www/redprogram/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_entry_points.py", line 43, in <module>
          def validate(eps: metadata.EntryPoints):
      AttributeError: module 'importlib.metadata' has no attribute 'EntryPoints'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I will add that I use django-bootstrap-form in a few other projects on the same computer but they were installed some time ago and work perfectly. There were no problems during the installation.

A few information:
Python 3.10
setuptools 5.5.1
pip 23.1.2

I uninstalled and install again setuptools, updated pip, updated wheel, installed libpq-dev python3-dev... nothing

**Why can't I install it now and what else can I do to install this add-on?**

I'm not proficient in Linux so please don't be too advanced. Thanks for any suggestion that might help.

Comment: What is the version of Django you are using? 
Also, are you using a virtual environment for running this project? 
Where the Python, Setuptools and pip version taken from within that virtual environment?

Comment: Since this is not a new project, I wanted to install Django 3.1.2
Of course I use virtual environment because I have several projects.
Setuptools and pip is used with virtual environment. Python is global.
I have a similar problem with installing django mysqlclient
The server hasn't been updated recently so I don't think there have been any changes since installing the previous new project.
I did a test on a virtual machine and installing this set went without any problems.